# Blender freezes when rendering

Tags: rendering

My specs are:
CPU. Intel Core i5-8300H 
GPU. NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 (4GB GDDR5)
RAM. 8GB DDR4, 2400 MHz.

Blender instantly freezes up the screen when the rendering button is issued and the only way to go around this is to do a restart. How can this problem be solved?

Comment: HI, welcome! Difficult to say exactly, but that suggest some sort of hardware issue. Maybe driver (check version/update), maybe memory (perform some test), maybe excessive heating (check temperature)... I've the same card on my laptop and that never happened to me.

Comment: are you using eevee or cycle? are you using CPU, GPU or both?

Comment: I've used the CPU, it freezes. The same thing happens when running Blender on the GPU. Cycle.

The drivers are all up to date. RAM is enough. Temperature stays at 50 85 degrees which is normal I guess.

Hmm, I still don't know what causes this.

I tried rendering the output as a jpeg file and it still freezes..